# golang: Stack Trace single routine when program crashes

Tags: go, stack-trace

I am just curious to know if there is a way to get my go application to only output the stack trace for the routine which panics (and subsequently dies) rather than all of my goroutines as there are quite a number of them.

I would assume that there is some form of flag which I can pass to go run or go build to do this but cannot seem to find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not aware of any flag to control this. As the panicing goroutine (should be) is the first it is trivial to just discard or ignore the rest, or?

Comment: I can't write a full answer now, but you should be able to do this by recovering, printing your stack and panicking again.

Comment: What @Tom means, I think, is that you should put a panic catch in main so that any panic will be caught by it.

Comment: Since Go 1.6 this is the default.

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps try (not tested) using [runtime.Stack](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Stack) in a defered function while modifying (for debug purposes) your existing code for debug purposes:

```
const debug = true //TODO turn off for production

func MyPotentiallyPanickingGoroutine() {
        if debug {
            buf := make([]byte, 1<<16)
            defer func() {
                    fmt.Printf("%s\n", runtime.Stack(buf, false))
            }()
        }

        // existing code follows
}
```